# SOSL Statement Example

Tags: sosl

Can someone please explain what the following query does..?

```
    List<List<sObject>> results = [FIND '4155557000' IN Phone FIELDS 
RETURNING Contact(Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName),
Lead(Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName), Account(Id, Phone, Name)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query will search for the number '4155557000' in the phone field of the Contact,Lead and Account objects. The Returning clause expresses which objects need to be searched, and what fields of any matched records should be returned as results.

The composition and meaning of SOSL is well explained in its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm)